# C# Soap response force decimal places on decimal field

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have system A which makes a request to a Soap web service hosted on system B.  Currently system B returns a decimal data type which is formatted to show 3 decimal places.  I used the wsdl.exe tool to generate classes and it just shows as a straight decimal.

I need to replicate system B with my own Soap service but I can't get the decimal field to show 3 decimal places.  I have no control over what system A is expecting and i am told that it must show decimals even if the value is round (e.g 500.000).

After reading lots of posts about formatting to strings then decimal parsing, nothing I do can force this behavior.  I have looked at Soap and XML attributes but nothing can seem to control this.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you returning a `decimal` value or a `double` value? If it's `decimal` and for the purpose of testing you hard-code the value to `500.000m`, does that work? If so, there are probably ways we can help...

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassingly it works!

```
if (_fd.CreditLimit.HasValue) {
  decimal _dd = Convert.ToDecimal(_fd.CreditLimit.Value.ToString("#.000"));
  //decimal _dd = 500.000m;
  _rv.CreditLimit = _dd;
}
```

I was breaking my code in Visual Studio and when i inspected the variable _dd it was showing 500.  However if i let Soap do its thing and return the result it shows 500.000 as the value.